# Flat-UI & AngularJS Radio Input Form Functionality

Tags: forms, angularjs

Using [Flat-ui](http://flat-ui.com/) with a form that contains some radio inputs which changes the format from standard bootstrap `<input type="radio"...` format to the following:

```
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" data-toggle="radio">
  Radio is off
</label>

<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" data-toggle="radio" checked>
  Radio is on
</label>
```

The problem is when I use `AngularJS` to process the `form` the values are not being stored in the associated object:

```
<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="1" data-toggle="radio" data-ng-model="regForm.accountType">
  Radio is off
</label>

<label class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="group1" value="2" data-toggle="radio" data-ng-model="regForm.accountType">
  Radio is on
</label>
```

*As an aside:  The radios' images are not appearing until after they are toggled? Has anyone else has this problem with flat-ui's kit?*

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for this problem.

https://gist.github.com/petehamilton/5993366

Another solution is to don't preventDefault event

https://github.com/designmodo/Flat-UI/issues/57